# Control the vertical space in multiple choice questions

Tags: spacing, exam

This is the screen shot of my customized multiple choice questions. (I have some modification to the `exam` class's multiple choice question, so that they can have images, see [How can I put a figure to the right of a multiple-choice question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141870/how-can-i-put-a-figure-to-the-right-of-a-multiple-choice-question) and the four choices are automatically aligned, see [How to automatically align the four choices of a multiple choice question in exam?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140923/how-to-automatically-align-the-four-choices-of-a-multiple-choice-question-in-exa))
[image]

You see, there are three vertical spaces need to be adjusted. But I still don't know how to adjust those three spaces. Here is the minimal test code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% the accumulated answers text
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\answertext}{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% adjust the lengths
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\parskip}{1.0cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\itemsep}{2.0cm}

\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{10pt}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% True or False questions
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94374/answerline-to-the-right-of-a-question-with-dot-line-between-answer-line-and-que
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength\answerspace
\setlength\answerspace{0.5in}
\newcommand\dottedanswerline[1][{}]{%
% One optional argument, the default value of which is empty.
%\unskip\linebreak[0]\enspace\hbox{}\nobreak\dotfill 
\unskip\nobreak\hfil\allowbreak\hbox{}\enspace\nobreak\dotfill
\ifprintanswers
    \hbox to \answerspace{(\hfil#1\hfil)}%
  \else
    \hbox to \answerspace{(\hfil)}%
    \xappto\answertext{\thequestion,#1\space}%
  \fi
}% dottedanswerline


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% multiply choice questions
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140923/how-to-automatically-align-the-four-choices-of-a-multiple-choice-question-in-exa
% also it support adding figures in the right corner
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141870/how-can-i-put-a-figure-to-the-right-of-a-multiple-choice-question
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newlength\choiceitemwidth
\newif\ifshowsolution \showsolutiontrue
\newcounter{choiceitem}%

\def\thechoiceitem{\Alph{choiceitem}}%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
%\def\makechoicelabel#1{#1\uline{\thechoiceitem.}\else\thechoiceitem.\fi\space} %underline the answer item label if we want to print the answer
\def\makechoicelabel#1{#1\framebox[1.25em][l]{\thechoiceitem.}\else\makebox[1.25em][l]{\thechoiceitem.}\fi} %underline the answer item label if we want to print the answer

\def\choice@mesureitem#1{\cr\stepcounter{choiceitem}\makechoicelabel#1}%

%measure the choices, this is the first time we need to parse the \BODY
\def\choicemesureitem{\@ifstar
  {\choice@mesureitem\ifprintanswers \xappto\theanswer{\thechoiceitem}\ignorespaces}%
  {\choice@mesureitem\iffalse}}%

\def\choice@blockitem#1{%
  \ifnum\value{choiceitem}>0\hfill\fi
  \egroup\hskip0pt
  \hbox to \choiceitemwidth\bgroup\hss\refstepcounter{choiceitem}\makechoicelabel#1}

\def\choiceblockitem{\@ifstar
  {\choice@blockitem\ifprintanswers\ignorespaces}%
  {\choice@blockitem\iffalse}}

\def\choice@paraitem#1{%
  \par\noindent\refstepcounter{choiceitem}\makechoicelabel#1\hangindent=1.25em\hangafter=1\relax}% only the first line need indent

\def\choiceparaitem{\@ifstar
  {\choice@paraitem\ifprintanswers\ignorespaces}%
  {\choice@paraitem\iffalse}}


\newdimen\qanswd
\newdimen\qanswdtmp
\newbox\qimgbox
\NewEnviron{items}[1][]{%
  \def\theanswer{}
  \begingroup
    \let\item\choicemesureitem
    \setcounter{choiceitem}{0}%
    \settowidth{\global\choiceitemwidth}{\vbox{\halign{##\hfil\cr\BODY\crcr}}}%
  \endgroup \dottedanswerline[\theanswer]
  \setbox\qimgbox\hbox{#1}%
  \setlist[trivlist]{nosep}
  \trivlist\item\relax%
  \qanswd=\linewidth%
  \advance\qanswd-\wd\qimgbox%
  % handle large images (leaving less than 30% space)
  \qanswdtmp=0.3\linewidth%
  \ifnum\qanswd<\qanswdtmp%
    %\strut\hfill% uncomment to right-align large images
    \unhbox\qimgbox%
    %\hfill\strut% uncomment this too to center them
    \par%
    \qanswd=\linewidth%
    \setbox\qimgbox\hbox{}%
  \fi%
  % end of handling for large images
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\qanswd}
  \trivlist\item\relax%
   \parindent0pt%  
  \setcounter{choiceitem}{0}%
  \ifdim\choiceitemwidth<0.25\columnwidth
    \choiceitemwidth=0.25\columnwidth
    \let\item\choiceblockitem
    \bgroup\BODY\hfill\egroup
  \else\ifdim\choiceitemwidth<0.5\columnwidth
    \choiceitemwidth=0.5\columnwidth
    \let\item\choiceblockitem
    \bgroup\BODY\hfill\egroup
  \else % \choiceitemwidth > 0.5\columnwidth
    \let\item\choiceparaitem
    \BODY
  \fi\fi
  \endtrivlist
  \end{minipage}%
  \adjustbox{valign=t}{\unhbox\qimgbox}
  \endtrivlist
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\section {Multiply Choice Questions}
\begin{questions}
\question 1111 text text text text text text text 
  \begin{items}
    \item foo
    \item bar
    \item*baz
    \item text text text text text text text 
  \end{items}

\question 2222 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  \begin{items}
    \item*   foo
    \item   bar
    \item   baz
    \item   text
  \end{items}

\end{questions}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ifprintanswers
    % do nothing
\else
    % this print the answertext
    \answertext
\fi

\end{document}
```

The minimal code may look a bit complex, because the customized item environment has a lot of code.

As I know, change the code

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
```

will change the whole three kinds a vertical spaces simultaneously. But I don't know how to adjust them individually. From the sample code, you will see the items were put in a `minipage`, but any one know how to adjust the margins before and after the `minipage`?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

If I follow egreg's advice(in comments), and change the code like below

```
\setlist[trivlist,1]{ topsep=0cm}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1.0cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.6}
%\setlength{\itemsep}{2.0cm}
```

[image: space bug2]

But the space before and after the items are still quite big.

If I change to the code below(topsep is -1cm):

```
\setlist[trivlist,1]{ topsep=-1cm}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1.0cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.6}
%\setlength{\itemsep}{2.0cm}
```

Then, I see it get a litter smaller space before the items.
[image: space bug 2]

So, I wondering why a -1cm is needed here? I mean I want to know how to exactly control the space before and after the items. Thanks.

**EDIT2**

I create a minimal test code and try to see how `minipage` and `trivlist` work, it looks like I can get the expect space, especially the space between question text and items are quite small, see below the code and the screen shot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[trivlist,1]{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.6}
\begin{document}

\noindent Question Question Question Question Question\par
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
    \trivlist %
    \item A.abc
    \item B.def
    \endtrivlist
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

This is the screen shot:

[image: space looks quite good]

It looks like this pure code does not expose the space issue.

Comment: Aside: I think it's called "multiple choice", not "multiply choice".

Comment: @JohnKormylo I want to make those vertical space the same length, and also make them a litter smaller value, so that the multiple choice questions looks quite compact. So, not adding spaces, but reduce spaces.

Comment: There is *no* space added between the choices; what you see is due the larger baseline skip that *you* impose. Before and after the choices, the added space is the standard `\topsep`.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the hint. If I comment out the line`\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}` and add a line `\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}`, I still get unequal spaces between items and before or after the items.

Comment: I see that `\setlist[trivlist,1]{ topsep=0cm}` this command can control the space after the question line and the choices, but still the space is a litter larger than vertical space between each items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the answer of this question[\topsep, \itemsep, \partopsep and \parsep - what does each of them mean (and what about the bottom)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300512/24012), I understand that the first vertical space is controlled by `\parsep`, and the third space is controlled by `\itemsep`+`\parsep`, so here is the setting code snippet I use, which gives such expected result. Thanks for the help and hint.

```
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0.5\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
   \setlength\partopsep{0pt} 
   \setlength\parsep{0pt}
}
```

Here is the screen shot:

[image: good space between items and questions]

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you don't like in the vertical spaces (marked red).  I'm not sure how you want to fix it.  The following will make the marked vertical spaces look nice (although my "nice" is not necessarily the same as yours).

```
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{\baselineskip}
  \addtolength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks for the help, I remembered you help me three years ago when I'm trying to adding images for the multiple choice questions.  It looks like controlling the space before and after the choices are not quite simple, you can see my updated question.  The main problem is that it's hard the set the space before and after the items.