# Simple multiple choice exam

Tags: exam

Good day. Im new to latex and I want ti create a simple multiple choice test as shown below:

1. What is the sum of the sides of a polygon called?

   ```
   A. Leg B. Perimeter C. Area D. Volume
   ```
2. Wat is the product of -2 and 3?

   A. -6        B. 6            C. 5        D. -5

*I want the A, B, C, D to be be aligned with the choices in the other numbers.

Comment: Thanks for telling us about your plans. However, the site is designed for questions and answers rather than personal announcements. Perhaps Facebook would be a better place for this?

Comment: Take a look on CTAN.  There are lots of packages and documentclasses for exams: https://ctan.org/topic/exam

Comment: If you have an actual question rather than looking for general guidance, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question.  For now I'm voting to close as "too broad".  Please ping me once you updated the question so I can retract the close vote or vote to reopen.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't think it is a 'broad' question. The question is how to align the choices across different MCQs.

Comment: See if this answer helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141147/117534

Answer (score 8):

You can use, for example, the package [`tasks`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\NewTasks[style=enumerate,counter-format=tsk[A].,label-width=3ex]{choice}[\item](4)

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item What is the sum of the sides of a polygon called?
  \begin{choice}
    \item Leg
    \item Perimeter
    \item Area
    \item Volume
  \end{choice}
  \item What is the product of $-2$ and $3$?
  \begin{choice}
    \item $-6$
    \item $6$
    \item $5$
    \item $-5$
  \end{choice}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It says that ep3l.sty not found

Comment: @KenMirasol Update your TeX distribution (TeX Live or whatever).