# Align enumeration list containing math items with tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, enumerate, enumitem

I'm trying to have the following horizontal alignment of (enumerated) questions, but for some reason there is a misalignment in all the columns except for the first. Or maybe it is the first that is misaligned, I can't understand. Is there an easy way for a rookie like me to fix this? If it can be done with another environment, other than tabular, or even with a new package, I would much appreciate it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}



    \begin{document}


    \noindent Να βρείτε το $\underset{x\to x_0}{\textlatin{lim}} f(x)$ όταν:
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\!\it\roman*\rm)]
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}}
        \item $x_0=1$ & \item $x_0=2$ & \item $x_0=3$ \\ \item $x_0=4$ & \item $x_0=5$ & \item $x_0=6$
    \end{tabular}
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the output you currently get? Probably, a sketch of the desired output would also be helpful to add.

Comment: You might want to try the `tasks` package.

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504658/134144

Comment: I added a screenshot like you suggested to show the problem of my code. I apologize for the delay. Also, thank you for the post in the link, I just checked it out and I know it will help a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the `tasks` package:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{tasks}

\settasks{
  counter-format=(tsk[r]),
  item-indent=4em,
  label-format=\itshape,
  label-width=3em,
  label-offset=0.5em,
  label-align=right,
}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Να βρείτε το $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ όταν:
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task $x_0=1$
\task $x_0=2$
\task $x_0=3$
\task $x_0=4$
\task $x_0=5$
\task $x_0=6$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how the limit operator is input. I'd avoid `\limits` for in line formulas, though.

If you want upright parentheses

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{tasks}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lparen}{}{\textup(}
\NewDocumentCommand{\rparen}{}{\/\textup)}

\settasks{
  counter-format=\lparen tsk[r]\rparen,
  item-indent=4em,
  label-format=\itshape,
  label-width=3em,
  label-offset=0.5em,
  label-align=right,
}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Να βρείτε το $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ όταν:
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task $x_0=1$
\task $x_0=2$
\task $x_0=3$
\task $x_0=4$
\task $x_0=5$
\task $x_0=6$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You, sir, are a true master of TeX. You have been a great help so many times, both in my questions and questions of others that helped me too. I used your solution, and I will read the manual of tasks package to learn it (not easy for me). Just one question: Can I have italics only in the enumeration and not in the parentheses?

Comment: @Laxuist Good question! See edit.

Answer (score 1):

There are all kinds of vertical separation/space inserted with the use of `\item`: `\topsep` for the first `\item`, `\itemsep` for subsequent items, `\parsep` and `\partopsep`. Adding the `nosep` option to your list ensures that no vertical spacing is inserted, resulting in the vertical alignment you seek.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent Να βρείτε το $\underset{x\to x_0}{\textlatin{lim}} f(x)$ όταν:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\!\itshape\roman*\rmfamily),nosep]
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}}
    \item $x_0=1$ & \item $x_0=2$ & \item $x_0=3$ \\ \item $x_0=4$ & \item $x_0=5$ & \item $x_0=6$
  \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your elegant solution. The reason I didn't use it is because I tried it in my document and it didn't work. But when I tried it in a new document (copied your whole code above) it worked! I have no idea why did this happen, it is beyond my reach.